# How to prepend partial branch name to git commit with husky

Tags: githooks, husky

I have a functional `commit-msg` git hook that takes the string from beginning up to the first underscore from a git branch's name and prepends it to the commit message.

For better understanding: The branch name is `JIRA-123_fix_problem`, the commit command goes: `git commit -m 'Fix problem'` and through the `commit-msg` hook the commit message will automatically be changed into `JIRA-123: Fix problem`.

Now we're using **Nuxt** for our current **Vuejs** project and this makes use of **husky**. We want to keep **husky** in this project. Unfortunately (and, I guess, intentionally), **husky** works by overwriting the git commit hooks, and thus the file `.git/hooks/commit-msg` I use will be overwritten by **husky** and the original `commit-msg` hook does not work any more.

How can I either prevent **husky** from overwriting the `commit-msg` hook or instruct **husky** to do the same thing?

I can't find any documentation for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally found (and verified) the soution:

[In this husky issue ("Support custom git hooks to be not overridden by husky #323")](https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/323#issuecomment-442790924) *typicode* says:

> Husky is overwriting file, because there [is] `# husky` in it. It checks for this string to know if it's a user script or if it has been generared by husky.
>
> If you delete `# husky`, it will never overwrite them again.

After I removed the `# husky` line, re-installing all node modules in our project finally keeps the `commit-msg` hook I want to use. I originally just copied & pasted the code while maintaining the `# husky` line from the scaffolding of the project.